# How to convert Timestamp to LocalDateTime preserving time zone?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone, timestamp

How to convert `Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime` preserving the time zone?

I tried using `TimestampObject.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate()` however this does not preserve time zone.

Comment: what do you meant by timestamp? do you mean long value  of date?

Comment: I suppose you mean `java.sql.Timestamp`, but it doesn’t have a time zone in it, so what do you mean by “preserve time zone”?

Comment: sorry you are right . In db it is stored in String format like this " *30-Jan-2018 5:17 pm -0800 UTC* someText " so how do i acquire time Zone .

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] so we can see what you're already doing that's not working?

Comment: There’s really a contradiction between *UTC* and *-0800*  in the string. I suppose it means *UTC-0800*. Can you confirm or correct?

Answer (score 2):

You should really use the proper datatype for storing your timestamp in your database. Depending on your exact requirements and the capabilities of your RDBMS this could be for example `timestamp with time zone` or `datetimeoffset` for MS. Then from Java store `OffsetDateTime` or just `Instant` objects into the database and retrieve the same type back. `OffsetDateTime` is called that because it holds an offset in it in addition to date and time-of-day. Its methods `toLocalDateTime` and `toLocalDate` preserve the offset in the sense that the time and the date they give agree with the original offset. Neither `LocalDate` nor `LocalDateTime` can hold an offset or time zone themselves. Avoid the long outdated `java.sql.Timestamp` class if you can.

Your string includes `-0800`, an offset from UTC, and then `UTC`, which usually would mean offset 0 from UTC, but in this case may mean that the former offset was from UTC. I hope you know because I don’t. An offset is not the same as a time zone: a time zone contains all historic and known future changes in offset for the location it represents.

Assuming that your database already contains strings (for example `varchar`), you may get the date, time and offset from them like this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("d-MMM-uuuu h:mm ")
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("a")
            .parseCaseSensitive()
            .appendPattern(" xx 'UTC'")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
    String timestampString = "30-Jan-2018 5:17 pm -0800 UTC someText";
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    OffsetDateTime dateTime
            = OffsetDateTime.from(timestampFormatter.parse(timestampString, pos));
    LocalDate date = dateTime.toLocalDate();
```

I am taking into account that the string contains `am` or `pm` in lowercase, where Java would normally expect uppercase, by parsing that bit case insensitively, and I check that the text `UTC` is there, but don’t use it for anything. The snippet produces an `OffsetDateTime` of `2018-01-30T17:17-08:00` and next a `LocalDate` of `2018-01-30`.